# How to add multiple concat in one query?

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT CONCAT(schedule, ' ', starttime) as timestamp  
from tblappointment

SELECT a.*, CONCAT(p.fname,' ',p.lname) AS pname 
FROM tblappointment a,tblpatient p 
WHERE p.id = a.patient_id
```

I want to combine them into one query. I don't know how to convert that code using subquery

Comment: OK, what's stopping you? i.e. what does your multiple concat query look like and what syntax error are you getting?

Comment: Please use JOIN instead of `FROM tblappointment a,tblpatient p `

Comment: Well did you try adding `,CONCAT(a.schedule, ' ', a.starttime) as timestamp` to the second query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add additional ones using commas. Make sure the column name `timestamp` isn't already declared. You may want to consider using joins and `GROUP BY` to avoid duplicate records.

```
SELECT 
a.*, 
CONCAT(p.fname,' ',p.lname) AS pname,
CONCAT(a.schedule, ' ', a.starttime) as timestamp  
FROM tblappointment a,tblpatient p 
WHERE p.id = a.patient_id
```

Comment: Please use JOIN instead of `FROM tblappointment a,tblpatient p`

Comment: Thank you, I already change it to inner join